# The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query - using lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying this code I saw in a tutorial:

```
 public ActionResult GetSearchRecord(string SearchText)
 {

   List<Unit_Of_Measurement> list = db.Unit_Of_Measurement.Where(x=>x.name.Contains(SearchText) && x.is_deleted == 0).Select(x => new Unit_Of_Measurement { name = x.name}).ToList();
   return PartialView("SearchPartial", list );

 }
```

This is the Unit_Of_Measurement model(I used db first approach when creating this):

```
 public partial class Unit_Of_Measurement
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Unit_Of_Measurement()
    {
        this.Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public byte is_deleted { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting this error

> The entity or complex type 'hwbModel.Unit_Of_Measurement' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: EF6 does not allow you to use `new SomeEntityType` inside the query. Either remove the `Select` or create another non entity class (a.k.a. DTO, ViewModel etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot project into model type directly. Try using annonymous type or DTO, that is data transfer object.

**Annonymous type**

```
List<Unit_Of_Measurement> list = db.Unit_Of_Measurement.Where(x=>x.name.Contains(SearchText) && x.is_deleted == 0).Select(x => new { name = x.name}).ToList().Select(x => new Unit_Of_Measurement { name = x.name}).ToList();
```

**Using DTO**

Create new class for DTO.

```
public class UnitOfMeasurementDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var list = db.Unit_Of_Measurement.Where(x=>x.name.Contains(SearchText) && x.is_deleted == 0).Select(x => new UnitOfMeasurementDTO { Name = x.name}).ToList();
```

Then you need to update your "PartialView" to support new DTO rather than Unit_Of_Measurement model.

**Update**

This is an Entity Framework (EF) restriction. LINQ to entities will convert your LINQ query in to command tree query which will execute against EF in order to return objects.

- Construct an ObjectQuery instance from ObjectContext.
- Compose a LINQ to Entities query in C# or Visual Basic by using the
  ObjectQuery instance.
- Convert LINQ standard query operators and expressions to command
  trees.
- Execute the query, in command tree representation, against the data
  source. Any exceptions thrown on the data source during execution are
  passed directly up to the client.
- Return query results back to the client.

There are some restrictions when building command trees which can be execute against EF, so that project into model type directly does not support EF. Which means nothing wrong in your LINQ query, but cannot execute against EF. Anonymous types are not tracked in EF and completely separate from your model, so that it will work without any issues. These restrictions may have introduced later versions of EF, you might have used old sample code.

Comment: Thank you. The anonymous type worked. However, I still don't understand why it worked. If you don't mind, can you explain it to me?